# install mysql on freebsd

Tags: unix, freebsd, unix-shell, mysql5

How to install Mysql on freebsd , i have tried a lot but after i am getting lot many error so i have removed it , but now i want to reinstall it so , can anyone suggest me the link / commands to install it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend a mysql 5.1 binary from: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.1.html

You can select freebsd from the dropdown.

Then follow the directions at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/binary-installation.html

These instructions are not bulletproof, so you may need to read a bit of documentation. Post questions if you have them.

Answer (score 3):

`make install clean -C /usr/ports/database/mysql51-server`

http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/ports.html

Answer (score 2):

Use binary package(it's easier than to compile from ports):

```
pkg_add -r mysql51-server
```